# JS: the text does not automatically color when I open the html file. Problem starting the function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have problems with the javascript script to color the text. It works correctly, but the text only colors if you click on the panel and press the "space" button on the PC keyboard. If you press any other key (even Enter), the text does not color.

[image]

I would like the script to activate automatically as soon as I open the html file, so that the text is automatically colored as soon as I open the file.

In the html i tried using the function as both `onchange` and `oninput`. While in the js file i call the `changeColor()` function after creating it, with the aim of executing it automatically as soon as you open the file, but it doesn't work. Sorry for the problem, but i'm new. How can i solve it?

**index.html**

```
  <div id="editor" contenteditable="true" oninput="showPreview();" onchange="changeColor();">&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
    &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p>
  </div>
    
    <h3>PREVIEW</h3>
    <div class="preview-area">
      <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
    </div>
```

**style.css**

```
#editor {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
.statement {
  color: orange;
}
```

**javascript.js**

```
// CHANGE COLOR TEXT
function changeColor() {

var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];
// Keyup event
document.querySelector("#editor").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    // Space key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
    var newHTML = "";
    // Loop through words
    str = e.target.innerText;
    (chunks = str
        .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
        .filter(Boolean)),
        (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
        acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase())
            ? `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>`
            : `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
        return acc;
        }, ""));
    e.target.innerHTML = markup;

    // Set cursor postion to end of text
    //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
    var child = e.target.children;
    var range = document.createRange();
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
    range.collapse(true);
    sel.removeAllRanges();
    sel.addRange(range);
    this.focus();
    }
})
}
    
changeColor()


//PREVIEW
function showPreview() {
    var editor = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;
  
    // var cssCode =
    //  "<style>" + document.getElementById("cssCode").value + "</style>";
    // var jsCode =
    //  "<scri" + "pt>" + document.getElementById("jsCode").value + "</scri" + "pt>";
    
    var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window").contentWindow.document;
    document.getElementById("preview-window").srcdoc = editor;
    frame.open();
    //frame.write(htmlCode + cssCode + jsCode);
    frame.write(editor);
    frame.close();
  }
  
  showPreview()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider refactoring the coloring portion of `changeColor()` into another function, and call it immediately in the JavaScript for the initial load:

```js
function applyColoring(element) {
  var keywords = ["DIV", "DIV", "H1", "H1", "P", "P", "HELLO", "<", ">", "/"];

  var newHTML = "";
  // Loop through words
  str = element.innerText;
  (chunks = str
    .split(new RegExp(keywords.map((w) => `(${w})`).join("|"), "i"))
    .filter(Boolean)),
    (markup = chunks.reduce((acc, chunk) => {
      acc += keywords.includes(chunk.toUpperCase())
        ? `<span class="statement">${chunk}</span>`
        : `<span class='other'>${chunk}</span>`;
      return acc;
    }, ""));
  element.innerHTML = markup;
}

// CHANGE COLOR TEXT
function changeColor() {
  // Keyup event
  document.querySelector("#editor").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
    // Space key pressed
    if (e.keyCode == 32) {
      applyColoring(e.target);

      // Set cursor postion to end of text
      //    document.querySelector('#editor').focus()
      var child = e.target.children;
      var range = document.createRange();
      var sel = window.getSelection();
      range.setStart(child[child.length - 1], 1);
      range.collapse(true);
      sel.removeAllRanges();
      sel.addRange(range);
      this.focus();
    }
  });
}

changeColor();
applyColoring(document.getElementById('editor'));

//PREVIEW
function showPreview() {
  var editor = document.getElementById("editor").innerText;

  // var cssCode =
  //  "<style>" + document.getElementById("cssCode").value + "</style>";
  // var jsCode =
  //  "<scri" + "pt>" + document.getElementById("jsCode").value + "</scri" + "pt>";

  var frame = document.getElementById("preview-window").contentWindow.document;
  document.getElementById("preview-window").srcdoc = editor;
  frame.open();
  //frame.write(htmlCode + cssCode + jsCode);
  frame.write(editor);
  frame.close();
}

showPreview();
```

```css
#editor {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #444;
  color: white;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: monospace;
  white-space: pre;
}
.statement {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<div
  id="editor"
  contenteditable="true"
  oninput="showPreview();"
  onchange="changeColor();"
>&lt;h1>This is a Heading&lt;/h1>
  &lt;p>This is a paragraph.&lt;/p></div>

<h3>PREVIEW</h3>
<div class="preview-area">
  <iframe id="preview-window"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works now. But I didn't understand why you created another function. Could you explain it to me better please (in a simple way, without getting too technical)? What is the purpose of the applyColoring function? What is the new purpose of the changeColor() function? (I saw you changed it a bit).

Comment: I created another function so that the code is kept [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). If your definition of explaining it "better" is "a simple way, without getting too technical", then no, I don't think I can. The purpose of the `applyColoring` function is to modify the HTML in the `#editor` element to colorize according to your existing code. The purpose of the `changeColor()` function is to register an event listener on the `#editor` element that listens for `keyup` events and recolorizes the content.

Comment: OK perfect. Thank you. I understand. I voted and accepted your answer. However in about 1 hour, I will post another similar question with the same code. If you want to, check it out :)